# Forwarding ports after carrier grade NAT?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, port-forwarding, nat

I cant forward ports anymore to my Xbox cause turns out my ISP recently refreshed IPs and all their IPs are public now and they say you can only forward ports if I request a static IP for a large amount of fee. 
Theyre greedy as hell! 
Anyway, some people are saying its impossible to forward ports now, some say i should use a VPN.

Is there really a possible way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, option: purchase access with a VPN service that allows for a static IP and port forwarding, you will be able to have clients talk directly to your device(s) as you'd expect.

Option two: Find a deal on a VPS ([Virtual Private Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server)) and configure a popular VPN software like OpenVPN yourself. End result is the same, configuration part is much more in-depth. Good learning experience if you're trying to find a reason to spend an afternoon educating yourself on light networking.

---

In that scenario the traffic would be routed as so:

```
You <-> ISP <-> VPN provider <-> other gamers
```

Any traffic from the outside world would end up through the VPN service, who pipes it directly to you.

No one would see your ISP's address, nor would their routing (for the sake of NAT) matter. Do check your router to see if it supports VPN client capabilities at that level. Then, you can connect your router to `$VPN_PROVIDER` in a 'set and forget' fashion. All traffic piped through it.

Bonus points:

- Added anonymity, your ISP can't snoop that traffic very easily when encrypted.
- Masks your actual IP, giving you another layer of protection from "doxing" and DDoS attacks.

---

Personally, I've been using nvpn.net for a few years and they are pretty reasonable.

Comment: How about a free vpn? i dont think i would pay for a service that ive no idea how to use

Comment: There aren't many providers that would offer a free VPN, because your traffic routing through there system is an inherent risk for them. Anything you're doing appears to be them, so if Joe Shmoe the illegal drug smuggler uses it, they'll bust down Honest Hank's door. :(

You can buy a month of VPN service from many places for $5 or less, if you would rather simply test something out. Additional question, what is your router's model number/name?

Comment: whats the cheapest vpn i can buy then just for forwarding ports to my xbox?

Comment: Would need to know if your router can support VPN client functionality, because your XBOX definitely will not. What is the model # of your home router?

Comment: so it will be dependent on my router? so technically the vpn will be installed on my router and any device connected to it willl have its own ip.. therefore enabling the ability to forward ports? anyway my router is AZTECH DSL5001EN

Comment: Comments aren't really meant for conversing of long discussions, please follow me here to a chat for this question: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/27014/discussion-on-answer-by-spacecrab-forwarding-ports-from-within-isp-level-nat-fir?tab=general