# Share VPN via wifi and forward ports?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, port-forwarding

This is a sequel to this thread: [Forwarding ports after carrier grade NAT?](https://superuser.com/questions/957918/forwarding-ports-after-carrier-grade-nat)

Anyway, someone said that I can download a free vpn (I still dont know what vpn to download) and share it via wifi.. So any device connected to it will be connected to the VPN.

Now I want to forward ports to the device connected to that vpn.. That device would be my xbox.. Im just wondering where I should configure the ports since normally I do it on the router page.. But with a vpn now, i dont know where to set it up.

What do you guys think? Is this even possible?

Comment: According to your last post, you can do all these things from your router settings, it's more stable & it's depend on your Firmware if there is an option for that or not, you can flash your router with other open source firmware

Comment: @IT_GUY my router isnt capable of that im sure. its not even vpn capable..

Comment: ok what model you are using?

Comment: @IT_GUY aztech 5001en

Comment: ops... no comment wait guys to help you :)