# Port forwarding failure

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, dhcp

I am trying to forward a port for Voobly and this is suggested by them [here](http://www.voobly.com/pages/view/177) to play games with better connection.

**Questions:**

- AFAIK static IP is required. Where do you make IP static? From computer or router? I already did it from computer (see [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNcf3.png)) and I read somewhere that if `ipconfig /all` [shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApFXo.png) that `DHCP Enabled No` then the IP is static. But the router says that DHCP is enabled. Which one is effective?
- I told by Voobly that DHCP could be on and just do DHCP address reservation. By referring to [this](http://www.tp-link.com.tr/faq-489.html) link, in my router (TP-LINK TD-W8961ND) I don't see MAC address of my computer's Ethernet adapter listed but only the phone connected to the router (see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGeDu.png) pic). With the MAC what I mean is shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V21JC.png) picture. Choosing manual configuration and typing the mentioned address and pressing save does do nothing. Why?

**Things have been done so far:**

- Referring to [this](https://portforward.com/tp-link/td-w8961n/) link, opened port 16000 UDP in the router (see [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkRY5.png)).
- DMZ and UPnP are off and router firewall is on as all are suggested by Voobly.
- Added inbound rule in Windows firewall for port 16000 UDP and specifically for Voobly client executable.
- Both [PFPortChecker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otuJX.png) and Voobly network [diagnostic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otuJX.png) report that the port is not open.
- Antivirus is off.

Comment: I would recommend that you remove your public IP address from this post, as opening ports, is making you vulnerable attacks from the internet.

Comment: It is possible that you are behind a Carrier-grade NAT that prevents inbound connections to your public IP because that IP is shared with other people.

Comment: Could you try to make a test with your windows firewall turned off, to eliminate this as a problem? I suspect it could be another process or service, that is using the port, and therefore it could be blocked by your PC.

Comment: @AndersGornitzka I already tried that and the result is the same.

Comment: If you do from a CMD prompt netstat -a, does it show that its listening for incomming connections on port 16000?

Comment: @AndersGornitzka nope

Comment: Based on [this](http://www.remoterig.com/wp/?page_id=3494) link I am behind CGN. I guess I need to follow [this](https://superuser.com/a/957927/277610) answer.

Comment: What steps did you go through, to see if you are behind the CGN?

Comment: @AndersGornitzka The steps are provided in the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Oh - nevermind, i didn't see that. So i assume that your WAN ip on your ADSL modem/Router were different from the IP showing from whatsmyip.org.

Comment: @AndersGornitzka Exactly and additionally its like `10.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

Comment: Then @GiantTree is most likely right, as the `10.0.0.0/8` address space is reserved for private use only, through RFC 1918. Essentially you will have to ask your ISP if its possible to open for the port and forward it to your router `10.xxx.xxx.xxx`, before you can do your own nat..

Answer (score 0):

You must order the additional service "Fixed IP" in your ISP. Without this internet provider blocks the incoming requests.

Comment: Is what you are suggesting the same as first option of [this](https://superuser.com/a/957927/277610) answer?

Comment: @Shibli So it's the same.

Comment: @Shibli Different providers can call the service in different ways. Can you add a link to the website of your ISP?

Comment: [Here](http://broadmax.net/) is the link although it is not in English.

Comment: @Shibli, Perhaps your provider does not offer that service. The site is little information on technical details package. Support does not correspond by e-mail but only through a telephone.
You can try the second method (option two) shown in your link.